# Python 3 on Terminal different from shell?

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I built a simple text game in python to show a friend, and it runs fine on shell but errors in terminal. Is there a difference in compiling for terminal vs shell in python?

In shell, this is what happens:
[image: test is an invalid input, so it asks you to type one of the answers and then when typing yes it continues]

But in terminal it gives me this error:
[image]

Is there any reason for this?

My code:

```
"""""~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~IMPORT PACKAGES~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"""""

from random import randint
import os
import copy
import math
import time
import pickle
import platform
import subprocess as sp

"""""~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~LOAD DATA/NEW GAME~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"""""

newData = {"assassin" : {'hp' : 100, 'atk' : 250, 'lvl' : 1, 'arm' : 0, 'pow' : {'name' : 'surprise attack', 'lvl' : 0}, 'xp' : 0},
                             "mage" : {'hp' : 100, 'atk' : 200, 'lvl' : 1, 'arm' : 0, 'pow' : {'name' : 'fire','lvl' : 0}, 'xp' : 0},
                             "knight" : {'hp' : 100, 'atk' : 150, 'lvl' : 1, 'arm' : 10, 'pow' : {'name' : 'dodging','lvl' : 0}, 'xp' : 0},
                             "healer" : {'hp' : 500, 'atk' : 50, 'lvl' : 1, 'arm' : 0, 'pow' : {'name' : 'healing','lvl' : 0}, 'xp' : 0}}


if platform.system()=='Windows':
    file = 'filepath'
elif platform.system()=='Darwin':
    file = 'filepath'

"""Clears screen"""
clear = lambda: os.system('cls' if platform.system()=='Windows' else 'clear')

print('Load data?')

while True:
    answer = input()


    if answer == 'yes':
        load_file = open(file, 'rb')
        characterData = pickle.load(load_file)
        load_file.close()
        break
    elif answer == 'no':
        print('Starting a new game...')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        characterData = copy.deepcopy(newData)
        save_file = open(file, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(characterData, save_file)
        save_file.close()
        break
    else:
        print('That input cannot be deciphered. Please type "yes" or "no".')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using Python 3.x in the shell but Python 2.x is used in the terminal. The `input()` function behaves differently in the two versions of Python.

Just make sure you are using Python 3.x in the terminal. If you want Python 2.x both times, change `input()` to `raw_input()`.